# Can't disable "Scan Organization Triggers" in Jenkins Github Org

Tags: jenkins, github

We're having problems with huge amounts of build on our Jenkins server. We think this is caused by automatic indexing, which we've tried to turn off on the Github Organization "folder":

However, in the individual github projects, the triggers are still enabled:

[image: screenshot of github project View Config page]

How can we disable it completely?

Answer (score 1):

It's messy but you can go into `$JENKINS_HOME` and under the `config.xml` for the repository change the trigger element to `<trigger\>` rather then the cron currently in place. This doesn't disable the manual scan though...